# How to properly track events on a embeded Spotify player?

Tags: javascript, spotify, snowplow

I want to track events (play, pause, seek, etc) on a embeded Spotify player. My idea is to send to Snowplow these events. The thing is that the embeded Spotify does not use **video** and **audio** HTML tags and all the tips that I have found so far on the internet does not help.

So the only idea that I had so far is to get the play/pause buttons and add event listeners to them using JS. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("play-button").addEventListener("click", function() {console.log('play pressed.')})
```

After that I would use Snowplow trackButtonClick. Something like this:

```
snowplowTracker.trackButtonClick('btn_spotify', 'Spotify button ');
```

Is there other way to track events on a embeded Spotify player for Snowplow? I checked Google Tag Manager too and there is no trigger for Spotify there. Any help?